# How to create a file using user input with assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to record in a file an user input, using assembly.

I'm working with this code but when the file is created, the input isn't recorded on the file correctly. Someone can help me with this? Here is my code:

```
.data

file1: .asciiz "file1.txt"
prompt: .asciiz "User entry\n"
buffer: .space 45

.text   

    la $a0,prompt
    li $v0,4
    syscall

    li $v0, 8
    li $a1, 454
    syscall
    move $s1, $v0
    j writeFile1

writeFile1: 
            li $v0, 13
            la $a0, file1
            li $a1, 1
            li $a2, 0
            syscall
            move $s6, $v0

            #write
            li $v0, 15
            move $a0, $s6
            la $a1, buffer 
            li $a2, 45
        syscall

        #close
        li $v0, 16
            move $a0, $s6
            syscall
            j exit



exit:   li  $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Comment: Define _"the input isn't recorded on the file correctly"_.

Comment: for example, when the input is "test", the output on file is:

4675 6e63 696f 6e6f 7520 6120 6573 6372
6974 6120 6e6f 2041 7271 7569 766f 2032
2e00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00

Comment: Well, the way you use syscall 8 doesn't make much sense. Refer to [the documentation](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) for its proper usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user input call did *not* setup the pointer to `buffer`. So, it would read into `prompt` instead. Also, the given length was `454` instead of the [intended] `45`. Further, this syscall does *not* return a length, so saving `v0` did nothing.

After fixing the above the program works. But, it would write a fixed length output so there were binary zeroes at the end.

I've added some code to calculate the string length (e.g. like `strlen`). I've also added sidebar comments to most lines. I highly recommend this for any asm. Anyway, here's the corrected program [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data

file1:      .asciiz     "file1.txt"
prompt:     .asciiz     "User entry\n"
buffer:     .space      46
    .eqv    BUFMAX      45              # usable buffer length (one less)

    .text

    # prompt user
    la      $a0,prompt                  # prompt string
    li      $v0,4                       # puts syscall number
    syscall

    # read user string
    li      $v0,8
    la      $a0,buffer                  # FIXME -- this was missing
    li      $a1,BUFMAX                  # FIXME -- this was 454
    syscall
    ###move $s1,$v0                     # FIXME -- does nothing v0 is not length

    ###li       $s1,BUFMAX              # use fixed length
    ###j        writeFile1              # would do write with zeroes in file

    # calculate string length (e.g. like strlen)
    move    $s1,$a0                     # point to buffer start
getlen:
    lb      $t0,0($s1)                  # get byte -- is it zero?
    addi    $s1,$s1,1                   # advance pointer
    bne     $t0,$zero,getlen            # no, loop
    sub     $s1,$s1,$a0                 # get length from end pointer
    subi    $s1,$s1,1                   # compensate for preincrement

writeFile1:
    # open the output file
    li      $v0,13                      # open syscall number
    la      $a0,file1                   # filename
    li      $a1,1                       # open for writing
    li      $a2,0                       # open mode
    syscall
    move    $s6,$v0                     # save fildes number

    # write
    li      $v0,15                      # write syscall number
    move    $a0,$s6                     # get fildes number
    la      $a1,buffer                  # get buffer pointer
    move    $a2,$s1                     # get buffer length
    syscall

    # close
    li      $v0,16
    move    $a0,$s6                     # get fildes number
    syscall
    j       exit

exit:
    li      $v0,10                      # exit syscall number
    syscall
```